# Algebraic law question for law identities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been given the example question...

We can derive the new law A ⊆ A ∪ B as follows:

- By Associativity and Idempotence, A ∪ (A ∪ B) = A ∪ B.
- Letting X = A and Y = A ∪ B, this says that X ∪ Y = Y.
- By the above, this means that X ⊆ Y; that is, that A ⊆ A ∪ B.

I don't understand where "A ∪ (A ∪ B)" originally comes from?

Comment: It's made up by the person writing the proof.  It's designed so that the final conclusion will follow.

Comment: As for why $A\cup (A\cup B)$ is true, note that by associativity $A\cup (A\cup B)=(A\cup A)\cup B$ and by idempotence $(A\cup A)\cup B=A\cup B$

Comment: @michael-burr How did the person make it up? What is the relevance to "A ⊆ A ∪ B"?

Comment: Work backwards, what do $X$ and $Y$ need to be in order to conclude the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Two sets, $C$ and $D$, are equal iff $C \subseteq D$ AND $D \subseteq C$. Also, $C \subseteq D$ (and vice versa) iff every element of $C$ is an element of $D$. You can use these properties to prove that $A \cup (A \cup B) = A \cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to prove that $A\subseteq A\cup B$.

Now, consider the statement that if $X\cup Y=Y$, then $X\subseteq Y$.  Working backwards, in order to get $A\subseteq A\cup B$ as the conclusion, you must use $X=A$ and $Y=A\cup B$.

Now, we must check the hypothesis of the statement above, in other words, one must show that $X\cup Y=Y$ or that $A\cup(A\cup B)=A\cup B$.  However, this is true as you state.

Therefore, since $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary in the statement above, using the special case where $X=A$ and $Y=A\cup B$, we get exactly the desired conclusion.  Therefore, we choose the $X=A$ and $Y=A\cup B$ in order to *engineer* that the desired conclusion occurs - $X$ and $Y$ are variables and we can choose them however we wish.